# Controller Action method only getting the first time. Why is it not getting hit again?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

When I click the FilterButton it hits the alert everytime, after every click.  However, the action method GridData is only getting hit the first time through. Do you know why?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#FilterButton').click(function () {

                alert('button clicked');

                var myGrid = jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                    url: '/Data/GridData/',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'POST',
                   ......
```

Here is the requested Action Method

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, string species, string methodOfTake, string outputType, string seasons, string years)
    {          

        var results = (from a in db.t_harvest_statistics_elk
                        where a.year == "2008" && a.unit_number == 1
                        orderby a.id
                        select new { a.id, a.year, a.unit_number, a.total_hunters, a.bulls, a.cows }).ToList(); 

        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        int totalRecords = results.Count();   
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

        var pageResults = results.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);           

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (
                from pageResult in pageResults
                select new
                {
                    id = pageResult.id,
                    cell = new[] { 
                                    pageResult.year.ToString(),
                                    "Add",
                                    pageResult.unit_number.ToString(),                                         
                                    pageResult.total_hunters.ToString(),
                                    pageResult.bulls.ToString(),
                                    "add",
                                    pageResult.cows.ToString(),
                                    "add",
                                    "add",
                                    "add"

            }
                }).ToArray()
        };


        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

Comment: Is your action method cached?  How are you sure your action method is only getting called the first time?  Did you put a breakpoint in your action method?

Comment: Hi Shark, yes I have a breakpoint.  It gets hit the first time but every click after it does not get hit.  I am not caching anything.

Comment: can you post your action method?

Comment: I just added the Action Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jqGrid control is an interesting beast.

What is happening here is that you're first call is *initialising the grid*, and therefore setting up the grid for the first time will initialise the data needed for the grid. This initialisation is calling the controller action and is the reason it's hitting the breakpoint the first time.

For each subsequent click, what's happening is that you're calling the jqGrid() method, but because it's already initialised, it's ignoring the call and therefore not setting the parameters you specify.

What you need to do instead is call the "setGridParam" method which will allow you to update the jqGrid parameters like so:

```
jQuery('#list').setGridParam({
                    url: '/Data/GridData/',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'POST',
                    ...
);
```

after you've changed the grid parameters, you need to trigger a refresh like so:

```
jQuery('#list').trigger("reloadGrid");
```

It's not the most intuitive setup, but this is how jqGrid works.

Comment: I added .setGridParam({ and the 'reloadGrid' piece and it didn't work. Then I just added the 'reloadGrid' section after my jqGrid and it hits my Action method on each click of the button.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, my answer could have been a little clearer. You need both bits to make it work, not just the first. Glad you got it sorted.